# Alternative to wadl2ava

Tags: java, marshalling, wsdl2java, wadl

This question might sense very broad. But So far I am seeing challenges to use [wadl2java maven plugin](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-wadl2javaMavenplugin). I am getting host of issues while marshalling Json based request body in my REST calls to Jaxb types So looking for a clearer and better solution for generating server side java codes from WADL file.

Comment: Can the great toolbox _OpenAPI_ (previously named _Swagger_) help you? If you have part of REST with Server or REST with Client exchanges to reconstruct, it is often useful.

Comment: Any doc or link to  generate java codes from wadl file using OpenAPI would be of great help. Thanks for the suggestion @MarcLeBihan